# mysql get ascii code dump for string

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, is there a way in a simple `SELECT` to obtain a sequence of ASCII code/code points for each character in a `varchar` value? I'm more familiar with Oracle, which has the [DUMP](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/dump.php) function that can be used for this.

For example, `select some_function('abcd')` would return something like `96,97,98,99`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is about the closest equivalent I'm aware of in MySQL:

```
mysql> select hex('abcd');
+-------------+
| hex('abcd') |
+-------------+
| 61626364    |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a mysql_function that will do that, but you can take the string in php, convert to an array, then take the ordinal of the character.

```
   $char_value_array = {};
    foreach($mysql_fetched_str as $char)
        array_push($char_value_array, ord($char)
```

Comment: I don't mind writing some procedural code to do it, if needed, as long as I can run it from a plain mysql client, but this is something I'm doing for debugging purposes so it needs to be inside the mysql client.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dump (s CHAR(20)) RETURNS CHAR(50) DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN
DECLARE result CHAR(50);
DECLARE i INT;
DECLARE l INT;

SET result = ASCII(SUBSTRING(s,1,1));
SET l = LENGTH(s);
SET i = 2;
WHILE (i <= l) DO 
    SET result = CONCAT(result, ',', ASCII(SUBSTRING(s,i,1)));
    SET i = i + 1;  
END WHILE;

RETURN result;
END;
```

And then use it in the SELECT:

```
SELECT dump('abcd') FROM test LIMIT 1
```

Increase CHAR(20) and CHAR(50) definitions if you need to use it with longer strings.