# Conversion of a string into characters in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I want to break a string into characters and store each in a different variable. If my string was `hello` I want a different variable for each of 'h' , 'e', 'l' ,'l', 'o'.

How can I do that in Mysql? Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: mysql is no  good for that, it is possibble and eays in mysql 8 and a lot harder in mysql 5, but if you don't need it for something else, don't do it.

Comment: Just to expand on the previous comment: mysql does not have an array type, so you cannot dynamically create the variables you need to contain each of the characters. There is also no split or explode function in mysql - kinda follows from the lack of arrays. Why do you need such a functionality in mysql?

Comment: I want to convert a string into ascii code, by using select ascii function it only converts the first character in the string therefore i was thinking to split the string into characters and convert them , then i can merge them by using concat function.

Comment: You should have asked your real question... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929318/mysql-get-ascii-code-dump-for-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use a recursive query to extract each character from the string and put it in a separate row:

```
set @word = 'hello';

with recursive cte as (
    select @word as word, left(@word, 1) as val, 1 as idx
    union all
    select word, substring(word, idx + 1, 1), idx + 1 
    from cte 
    where idx < char_length(word)
)
select val from cte order by idx
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=375eb24b5d90f7b048788d3e0123c057)**:

```
| val |
| :-- |
| h   |
| e   |
| l   |
| l   |
| o   |
```

In earlier versions, you would typically use a table of numbers for this.

If you want to rebuild the string as a sequence of ascii characters, as indicated in the comments, you can change the outer query as follows:

```
select group_concat(ascii(val) order by idx separator '-') ascii_word from cte
```

You can adapt the `separator` to whatever suits you best. This **[produces](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d60a0740031665788632de1f1231f594)**:

```
| ascii_word          |
| :------------------ |
| 104-101-108-108-111 |
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Could you please explain the code above?