# MySQL INNER JOIN without duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. One of them has duplicates within its IDs, the other table is unique.
I want to inner join only with the id with content.

Sample for table textinfo

| ID | Content |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | aaaa |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | bbbb |
| 2 |  |
| 3 | cccc |
| 3 |  |

```
SELECT * 
FROM infotext a 
INNER JOIN article b ON a.ID = b.InfotextID 
AND a.Content <> ''
```

I know this cannot work, but I don't know how to query only for the content rows.

The result after this query has a lot of duplicates in the articles with different contents.

Comment: Why do you say this cannot work? Did you try it? Is the `content` an empty string or is it NULL?

Comment: Are the blank contents values empty string ('') or null values? The two are not the same and need to be tested differently.

Comment: BillKarwin I tried the query, but I have a lot of multiple articles with different contents. The content is Empty. It is not NULL.

Comment: A good practice is to not use `SELECT *` , but `SELECT a.*` in your case

Comment: Please provide a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0) with the problem

Comment: @ErgestBasha: In my original query I dont use the *. Instead I ask for b.article, a.content

Comment: I wonder if there is actually white space or non-printing characters in `content`? Could you test `SELECT id, CHAR_LENGTH(content), content FROM infotext WHERE content <> ''`?

Comment: @ManfredSinger if the content is empty and not null, then your query is completely fine. If it is not fine, then what looks like an empty is string is not an empty string. It may contain non-printable characters like form feed or line feed. Converting your "blank" strings to their character code helps you to identify the content and filter it out. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929318/mysql-get-ascii-code-dump-for-string

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the empty rows are `null` or `''`, trimming white characters:

```
SELECT * FROM infotext a INNER JOIN article b ON a.ID = b.InfotextID AND TRIM(COALESCE(a.Content, '')) <> ''
```

Comment: I checked it already. The content is empty, not NULL

Comment: @ManfredSinger it is possible that you have some white characters stored as values, like spaces or tabs. I have edited my answer. Can you test the current suggested code?

Comment: @ManfredSinger also, how did you check whether the content is not `null`? Have you run `select count(*) from textinfo where Content is null;`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try also :

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM infotext a INNER JOIN article b ON a.ID = b.InfotextID AND a.Content <> '' GROUP BY b.InfotextID
```